# TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable, csv file

Tags: python, csv, openpyxl

I am getting the typeerror: 'generator' object is not subscriptable when trying to make lists of information in several csv files, sort them so that I get the information I need and put that information into a new .xlsx file. I am wondering if anyone here can help me with where I am going wrong. Is it the csv files that cannot be accessed or is there something wrong with my code?
(I did not add the entire code, only the code where I get the error)

Code:

```
import csv
import operator
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
import os
import logging

def opencsv(csvfile):
    csvdata = []
    with open(csvfile, encoding='utf-8-sig') as csv_input:
        try:
            reader = csv.reader(csv_input, delimiter=';')
            for row in reader:
                key_1 = row[0]
                key_2 = row[1]
                1_2 = key_1.split(';')
                2_1 = key_2.split(';')


                csvdata.append(list+link)
                sortedlist = sorted(csvdata, key=operator.itemgetter(0), 
                reverse=False)
        return sortedlist
    finally:
        csv_input.close()

def copycsv(excel_file, csvfile):
    rel_path_xlsx = r'C:\Myfolder\xlsx'
rel_path_csv = r'C:\Myfolder\CSV'
wb1 = load_workbook(rel_path_xlsx+"\\"+excel_file)
wb2 = Workbook()
ws1 = wb1.active
ws2 = wb2.active

sortedlist = opencsv(rel_path_csv+"\\"+csvfile)
listed = sorted(sortedlist, key=operator.itemgetter(0), reverse=False)
for info in listed:
    ws2.append(info)

col_v = ws2.columns[0] #line 39, error
col_n = ws2.columns[1] 

for idx, cell in enumerate(col_v, 1):
    ws1.cell(row=idx, column=4).value = cell.value

for idx, cell in enumerate(col_n, 1):
    ws1.cell(row=idx, column=5).value = cell.value

wb1.save(r"C:\Myfolder"+"\\"+"file_"+excel_file)


def copyxlsx(rel_path_xlsx, rel_path_csv):
    for filename in zip(sorted(os.listdir(rel_path_xlsx)), 
    sorted(os.listdir(rel_path_csv))):
    print(filename[0], filename[1])
    copycsv(filename[0], filename[1]) #line 55, error

Traceback (most recent call last):
line 55, in copyxlsx
   copycsv(filename[0], filename[1])
line 39, in copycsv
   col_v =ws2.columns[0]
TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable
```

I am quite new to python, so any help will be highly appreciated! Working in Python3.4.1

Comment: Bare minimum you could have posted the line number of the error. But generallly you have to post the full stacktrace. Do you expect us to carefully read everyline iin your code looking for a line that can possibly throw that error http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry, I have added the lines that get the error now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`worksheet.columns` returns a generator (as the error suggests). You'll need to convert it to a subscriptable object (ie list or tuple) in order to get a column by index:

```
cols = tuple(ws2.columns)
col_v = cols[0]
col_n = cols[1]
```

Or even better, assuming there are only 2 columns:

```
col_v, col_n = tuple(ws2.columns)
```

Or if there are more than 2 columns, you don't care about the rest and using Python 3:

```
col_v, col_n, *_ = tuple(ws2.columns)
```

Note this will create a useless list in memory. You could also do
`col_v, col_n = tuple(ws2.columns)[:2]` that works in both Python 2 and 3, and won't create a needless list in memory.

Comment: Or call `col_v = next(ws2.columns); col_n = next(ws2.columns)` and dont care about size

Answer (score 3):

You're calling `columns` method on ws2, which returns a *generator* rather than a list. You cannot access generator's values using index, so you have two options:

1) read all values from a generator at once and create a list of them, then operate on the list:

```
column_list = list(ws2.columns)
col_v = column_list[0]
col_n = column_list[1]
```

2) read only the first two values using `next` function:

```
col_v = next(ws2.columns)
col_n = next(ws2.columns)
```

Method 2 is preferable if your generator returns a **long** sequence of items, so you don't want to create a memory-hogging list of all of them. In your case, it probably doesn't matter.