# Openpyxl with IronPython: 'Sequence' object is not subscriptable

Tags: ironpython, openpyxl

With a usual python the openpyxl library works fine but I'm forced to use IronPython(2.7.3) in my case. At the beginning

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws['A1'] = 42
wb.save("D:/Test/result1.xlsx")
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython.2.7\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workboo
k\workbook.py", line 367, in save
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython.2.7\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\
excel.py", line 284, in save_workbook
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython.2.7\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\
excel.py", line 266, in save
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython.2.7\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\
excel.py", line 73, in write_data
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython.2.7\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\
workbook.py", line 36, in write_root_rels
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython.2.7\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\packagi
ng\relationship.py", line 67, in append
TypeError: 'Sequence' object is not subscriptable
```

I found this post but I can not make out how it can help in my case:
[TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable, csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44257659/typeerror-generator-object-is-not-subscriptable-csv-file)

Comment: You need to convert your Sequence object into a list or tuple. The Sequence object is on line 67.

Comment: AFAIK openpyxl will not run on IronPython due to the descriptors.